# Network protocol implementation like QNAM with delayed processing of requests

Tags: qt, qt4

I need to implement network protocol  working over tcp that basically works next way:
There is requests that are pushed and answers that are read (only one party can initiate request).
I do want to implement it in a way like QNetworkAccessManager: when "requestst is sent, QNAM return a pointer to reply, once requests is served - there is a signal and the result can be used from "reply" object. 
I do want to implement it without multithreading.

The major problem is next:

If socket is not connected I have 3 options:
1) return an error (returning null pointeter to reply object is like returning error)
2) emit "finish" from inside "sendRequest" (this is most evil approach)
3) return "reply" from "sendRequest" and later emit signal that request failed. (most wanted)

I really like 3-rd option but the only way I see now is to use timer with 1 ms one shot call - that basically looks like wrong path to implement such thing,
How can I make delayed execution of slot (with passing some parameter like coockie to request)?
It will be good if there is a way to send request delayed as well (like push request to queue, return from call with "reply" object and after then send actual request over network).
All this looks like dealing with event - but I am not sure how best to deal with this subject.
What is the best practice to implement such protocol?
Any advice?